# Should "it" be used in "There is a table that has a book on (it)"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, personal-pronouns

Is this sentence grammatically correct?:

> There is a table that has a book on it.

Can I say (or why can't I say if not?):

> There is a table that has a book on.

Comment: The near-superimposition of [these two Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=table+with+books+on%2Ctable+with+books+on+it&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctable%20with%20books%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctable%20with%20books%20on%20it%3B%2Cc0) indicates that the inclusion of 'it' is the idiomatic choice, at least for 'table with books on' vs 'table with books on it'. And to my ear, 'table that has a book on.' sounds a lot  less idiomatic than 'table with a book on.'. // Why? 'He has a black hat/coat on.' is perfectly idiomatic....

Comment: So idiomaticity and logic, as usual, seem not to match up, at least on the surface. // Why can't you say "table that has a book on it."? Nobody's going to stop you (unless they have an interest in how you use the language), but you won't sound like the average native speaker.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Problem is, it's one of those examples where there's no data to go on. When you actually click on "table with books on" to look at the examples, there's only three or four - and two of those don't have an "it". Alhtough, I would agree that an "it" is needed, of course.

Comment: @Araucaria This looks like a simple case of a stranded prep being ungrammatical. And see if you can spot the errors in JL's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - *There is a table [that has a book on it].*

This is a grammatical sentence. The restrictive relative clause

- [***that*** has a book on **it**]

modifies its antecedent noun phrase *a table*, and contains two noun phrases (*that*, the subject relative pronoun, and *it*, the object of the preposition *on*) which both refer to *a table*.

This is grammatical because the clause is grammatical as a simple sentence

- ***The table***  has a book on **it**.

The second sentence

> - **There is a table [that has a book on].*

is ungrammatical (that's what the asterisk means) because the supposed relative clause

- [*that has a book on*]

is not grammatical as a simple sentence

- **The table has a book on.*

and therefore can't be grammatical as a relative clause.

It's tempting to strand prepositions in relative clauses, like

- *The man put the book on a table; what color is the table that he put it on?*

but you can **only** do that when the relative pronoun *that* (or *which*, or *who*, depending) is the object of the preposition. In

- *a table **that** has a book on **it***

the relative pronoun *that* is already the subject and can't be moved or deleted, so the *it* that's the object of *on* is **not** a relative pronoun and can't be deleted or moved either.

Comment: But 'He has a new coat on' _is_ acceptable. Is 'have on' more unitary/cohesive in this case?

Comment: "The table had on a book" versus "I had on a winter coat"--"to have on" meaning "to be wearing" is possibly a phrasal verb.